# ERROR : adding <div> container to function.php

Tags: php, html, syntax-error

I am getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u7mtb69/public_html/wpsitehrhhw/wp-content/themes/hrhhw.1.1/functions.php on line 1201

I am trying to add meta boxes to a custom post section in my function.php file.

The file works great, until I add the `<div>` container, then I get an error - but the container looks correct.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

```
// Add WHEELS meta boxes

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'wheel_meta_boxes' );
    function wheel_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box(
        'wheel_info',
        __( 'Wheel Info'),
        'wheel_info_div',
        'wheels'
        );
    }

    function wheel_info_div( $post ) {
      // Use nonce for verification
      wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'wheel_noncename' );
    }

// WHEELS fields for data entry

<div>
    <label for="tire_code">
        <?php _e("Tire Code");?>
    </label>
        <input type="text" name="tire_code" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tire_code', true);?>" />
        <br>

    <label for="tire_name">
        <?php _e("Tire Name");?>
    </label>
        <input type="text" name="tire_name" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tire_name', true);?>" />
        <br>

    <label for="tire_bname">
        <?php _e("Tire Brand");?>
    </label>
        <input type="text" name="tire_bname" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tire_bname', true);?>" />
        <br>

    <input type="button" value="Create" id="create" />
    <input type="button" value="Replace" id="replace" />
    </div>

// NEXT

// END

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you put HTML inside a PHP block. Don't do that.

You must remember that PHP and HTML are completely distinct. There is no relationship whatsoever, other than that the HTML your browser sees is the *result* of a PHP interpreter running your PHP script (which may include some hard-coded HTML to keep in the output, like your `<div>`). So when you see a PHP error, it's not going to be HTML at fault.

---

### Wrong:

```
<?php
$somePHPCodeHere = 3;

<p>Some HTML here.</p>
?>
```

### Right:

```
<?php
$somePHPCodeHere = 3;
?>

<p>Some HTML here.</p>
```

Comment: Thanx, it helped get rid of the error, but now it puts the input at the top of the screen of all admin menus. So, I will work that and see what I can do.

Comment: I think you should read through the PHP manual. You may be misunderstanding how PHP runs and what it does, and where its output goes.

Answer (score 0):

In other words: You just need to add the closing php tag `?>` right after this line:

```
// WHEELS fields for data entry
?>
```